# How can a CountDownLatch object be passed to the constructor of a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was studying Threads in Java and I saw that Threads have the following types of constructors.

> Thread()
> Thread(Runnable target) 
> Thread(Runnable target, String name) 
> Thread(String name): Allocates a new Thread object 
> Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target) 
> Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name)
> Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize) 
> Thread(ThreadGroup group, String name)

But while trying out a few sample programs, I saw that the below code does not give any error:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    String name;
    CountDownLatch cdl;
    
    MyThread(CountDownLatch cdl, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cdl = cdl;
        new Thread(this);
    }
```

So, more specifically, what is the line `new Thread(this)` doing?

Comment: Is doing nothing at all, creates an object but does not saves its reference to later call .start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is actually not a `Thread` but a `Runnable` object. So `new Thread(this)` means constructing a new `Thread` object given with constructor argument a `Runnable` object (`MyThread` itself).

Comment: Understood. But what does the line itself do? I know that constructors do not have a return type, so what effect does the line have?

Comment: @Lycanthropeus The class should have `run()` method. It would execute Runnable if the line were `new Thread(this).start();`

Comment: That line `new Thread(this).start()` appears in the main method, but not in the class definition.

Comment: @Lycanthropeus Without `.start()`, it will do nothing.